# 「確認いたします」の返事ことば

Tags: business-japanese

ビジネスの会話で相手が「確認いたします」という時に自分はどう返事すれば良いでしょうか。

現在、「お願い致します。」と返事していますが、
もっとも丁寧な返事などがありましたら教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お手数おかけいたします。

お忙しい所かと思いますが何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

などでしょうか。私の場合は。